# Javascript | jspdf html2canvas - Al generar el pdf se corta el documento, no toma todo el ancho de la web

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

Al generar el pdf mediante jsPDF y html2canvas, genere un pdf cortado, es decir, no toma todo el ancho de la web. ¿Qué sucede?

**Anchura de pdf generado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
  function genPDF() {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("testDiv"),{
            onrendered: (canvas)=>{
                var pdf = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                
                const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
                doc.addImage(pdf, 'JPEG',1,1);
                doc.save('test.pdf');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**template:**

```
<div class="container w-100" id="testDiv">

    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8">
            <div class="text-right">
                <button onclick="genPDF();">genPDF </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--TITLE-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            
            <div style="background-color:rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)" class="alert alert-primary text-white" role="alert">
                <h2 class="text-dark">Estadística Mantenimiento Preventivo</h2>
...
            </div> 
         </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no tengo claro el funcionamiento, he encontrado por ahí un código que parece ser que toma la anchura del pdf como valor para generar el pdf:

**Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
  function genPDF() {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("testDiv"),{
            onrendered: (canvas)=>{
                var pdf = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                
                var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");

var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
                
doc.addImage(pdf, 'JPEG', 0, 0, width, height);
                doc.save('test.pdf');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```